# Identifying repeated fields in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have an SQL query that returns a column like this:

```
foo
-----------
1200
1200
1201
1200
1200
1202
1202
1202
```

It has already been ordered in a specific way, and I would like to perform another query on this result set to ID the repeated data like this:

```
foo    ID
----   ----
1200   1
1200   1
1201   2
1200   3
1200   3
1202   4
1202   4
1202   4
```

It's important that the second group of 1200 is identified as separate from the first. Every variation of OVER/PARTITION seems to want to lump both groups together. Is there a way to window the partition to only these repeated groups?

Edit:
This is for Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: How large is your resultset? Have you considered looping through the resultset and creating the Ids?

Comment: Result set is fairly small, maybe a few hundred at most. I have not considered looping, I'll Google it.

Comment: Yeah in this case try cursor.

Comment: What is the SQL Query that returns that result set? Can we just assume it is `SELECT col1 FROM YourTable ORDER BY col2` for the sake of argument? Also can you adjust that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution using a cursor and a temporary table to hold the results.

```
DECLARE @foo INT
DECLARE @previousfoo INT = -1
DECLARE @id INT = 0
DECLARE @getid CURSOR

DECLARE @resultstable TABLE 
(
    primaryId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    foo INT,    
    id int null 
)

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
SELECT originaltable.foo
FROM   originaltable

OPEN @getid
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO @foo
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF (@foo <> @previousfoo)
    BEGIN
        SET @id = @id + 1
    END

    INSERT INTO @resultstable VALUES (@foo, @id)
    SET @previousfoo = @foo

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getid INTO @foo
END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will be the fastest results...

```
select main.num, main.id from
(select x.num,row_number() 
over (order by (select 0)) as id 
from (select distinct num from num) x) main
join 
(select num, row_number() over(order by (select 0)) as ordering
 from num) x2 on 
x2.num=main.num
order by x2.ordering
```

Assuming the table "num" has a column "num" that contains your data, in the order-- of course num could be made into a view or a "with" for your original query.

Please see the following [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab579/16)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this without a `CURSOR`

```
-- Create a temporay table
DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
    SeqID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    foo INT,    
    id int null 
)


DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @j INT
DECLARE @k INT
declare @tFoo INT
declare @oldFoo INT

SET @k = 0
set @oldFoo = 0



-- Insert data into the temporary table
INSERT INTO @table(foo) 
SELECT 1200
INSERT INTO @table(foo) 
SELECT 1200
INSERT INTO @table(foo) 
SELECT 1201
INSERT INTO @table(foo) 
SELECT 1200
INSERT INTO @table(foo) 
SELECT 1200
INSERT INTO @table(foo) 
SELECT 1202
INSERT INTO @table(foo) 
SELECT 1202
INSERT INTO @table(foo) 
SELECT 1202

-- Get the max and min SeqIDs to loop through
SELECT @i = MIN(SeqID) FROM @table
SELECT @j = MAX(SeqID) FROM @table


-- Loop through the temp table using the SeqID indentity column
WHILE (@i <= @j)
BEGIN
  SELECT @tFoo = foo FROM @table WHERE SeqID = @i

  if @oldFoo <> @tFoo
    set @k = @k + 1 

  update @table set id = @k where SeqID = @i    

  SET @oldFoo = @tFoo
  -- Increment the counter
  SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * from @table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using cursors but it does not look nice (at least what I came up with). So 1) I assume you have PK column which orders your main values.
Then 2) I assume you have an ID column which you want to set.

```
    create table tbl(foo int, pk int, id int);

    insert into tbl(foo, pk) values (1100, 5);
    insert into tbl(foo, pk) values (1200, 10);
    insert into tbl(foo, pk) values (1200, 20);
    insert into tbl(foo, pk) values (1201, 30);
    insert into tbl(foo, pk) values (1200, 40);
    insert into tbl(foo, pk) values (1200, 50);

    insert into tbl(foo, pk) values (1202, 60);
    insert into tbl(foo, pk) values (1202, 70);
    insert into tbl(foo, pk) values (1202, 80);
    insert into tbl(foo, pk) values (1202, 90);
```

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdaaa/2

```
    update tbl
    set
    ID = 1 



    update t

    set

    t.ID = m.RN2 

    from

    tbl t 

    join 

    (


    select

    y1.RN as RN1, y1.PK as PK1,
    y2.RN as RN2, y2.PK as PK2

    FROM

    (

    SELECT

    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.pk1 ASC) AS rn,

    x.pk1 AS pk

    FROM
    (
    SELECT t1.pk AS pk1, t2.pk AS pk2
    FROM
    tbl t1
    LEFT JOIN tbl t2 ON
    (
    (t1.pk < t2.pk AND t1.foo = t2.foo)
    AND
    (
      NOT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT tMid.pk FROM
        tbl tMid WHERE
        tMid.pk < t2.pk
        AND
        tMid.pk > t1.pk
      )
    )
    )
    ) x WHERE x.pk2 IS NULL


    ) y1


    left join 




    (

    SELECT

    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.pk1 ASC) AS rn,

    x.pk1 AS pk

    FROM
    (
    SELECT t1.pk AS pk1, t2.pk AS pk2
    FROM
    tbl t1
    LEFT JOIN tbl t2 ON
    (
    (t1.pk < t2.pk AND t1.foo = t2.foo)
    AND
    (
      NOT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT tMid.pk FROM
        tbl tMid WHERE
        tMid.pk < t2.pk
        AND
        tMid.pk > t1.pk
      )
    )
    )
    ) x WHERE x.pk2 IS NULL


    ) y2 on y1.RN = y2.RN - 1 

    ) m on 

    (
    (t.pk > m.pk1 and ((m.pk2 is not null ) and (t.pk <= m.pk2)))
    -- or
    -- (t.pk<=m.pk1)
    )
```

Comment: If some of the SQL gurus here can try this and let me know if it's logically correctl, I would appreciate it. To me it looks good, I tested it quite seriously.